# При открытии Google sheets переход на ячейку с текущей датой

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть скрипт, который при открытии google таблицы переходит на ячейку с текущей датой. Все работает, если дата указана в столбце "А". На некоторых листах дата находится в столбце "B". Соответственно скрипт перестает работать. Прошу Вашей помощи в доработке скрипта. Благодарю.
Пример:
[Google Таблица](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kbhF9fuyouh48HXYFdr0C9stF3sDxtwmsdsO1-mnh4M/edit#gid=0)

```
function onOpen() {
 var menu = [{name: "Перейти к сегодняшней дате", functionName: "jumpToDate"}];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Настройки(NEW)", menu);
 jumpToDate();
}

function jumpToDate() {
 // Activate cell with current date
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(),
      data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(),
      now = new Date(),
      columnWithDate = 0,
      i, delta,
      epsilonInMs = 0;
  for (i = 0; data.length > i; i++) {
    delta = now - new Date(data[i][columnWithDate]);
    if (delta < epsilonInMs) break;
  }
  sheet.getRange(i, columnWithDate + 1).activate();
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: При открытии/обновлении google таблицы курсор встает на текущую дату(ячейку), которая находится в столбце "А"(Пример: Сегодня 04.11.2021, в столбце есть дата 04.11.2021 - курсор встает на данную дату). Сделано это для того, чтоб не листать руками вниз, так как обьем строк более 20к. Так вот, есть несколько листов, где дата находится не в столбце "А", а в столбце "В". Изменить данные таблицы я не смогу, так как сломается структура. Код я указал вышел.

Comment: Пример Таблицы несудьба добавить?